# print statement returning without space in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
class Student(Person):
    
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber,scores):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.idNumber = idNumber
        self.testscores = scores

    def calculate(self):
        average = sum(self.testscores) / len(self.testscores)
        if average>=90 and average<=100 :
            return'O'
        elif average>=80 and average<90 :
            return'E'
        elif average>=70 and average<80 :
            return'A'
        elif average>=55 and average<70 :
            return'P'
        elif average>=40 and average<55 :
            return'D'
        else:
            return'T'
```

The statement : `print("Grade: ", s.calculate())` returns `Grade:  O` (two spaces) instead of `Grade: O` (single space).

Since the above print statement is in locked stub code I can't modify it.

Is there anyway I can remove the extra space while returning from calculate function?

**Edit**: For better understanding of the problem consider this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS7FE.png)
in which the only difference is in my output's and expected output's third statement because of additional space.

Comment: Where exactly is the extra space? How do you see it on screen? Please post a proper [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure they are spaces and not line breaks?

Comment: As always, the answer to the question "Can I make someone else's code do something different without changing the code?" is "Not without doing something gross". Contact the author/maintainer of that code and have them fix the double space thing.

Comment: That `print` inherently produces two spaces: one explicitly from the string literal, one implicitly from the separator between items.  In Python 2.x you could hack out that second space within `calculate()` (via `sys.stdout.softspace = False`); in 3.x I don't believe there's any way without modifying the `print`.

Answer (score 3):

The `print` function prints each of its arguments with a space as a delimiter already, so by adding a space in `"Grade: "`, you're making it print another space between the colon and the grade. Simply replace `"Grade: "` with `"Grade:"` and it will output without the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `sep=''`, i.e. an empty string:

```
print('Grade: ', s.calculate(), sep='')
```

Or you can remove the space from your first argument:

```
print('Grade:', s.calculate())
```

Alternatively, you can use string formatting:

```
print(f'Grade: {s.calculate()}')          # 3.6+
print('Grade: {}'.format(s.calculate()))  # pre-3.6
```

To troubleshoot such problems, you can use the built-in `help`, which tells you the default argument for `sep` is a single space:

```
help(print)

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

    ...
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    ...
```

Interestingly, the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) have got it wrong:

> **print**(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed
>   by end. sep, end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword
>   arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the above print statement is in locked stub code I can't modify it.
>
> Is there anyway I can remove the extra space while returning from calculate function?

If I not misunderstand, you can change `caculate` function, but not `print`, and you want just see one space in output, and you are in python3.

Then you can use backspace `\b`, change E.g. `return 'O'` to `return '\bO'`, and other return need to be changed also.

A simple code for your quick test:

```
def fun():
  return 'O'

def fun2():
  return '\bO'

print("Grade: ", fun())
print("Grade: ", fun2())
```

Comment: It does work on my editor but not on the coding platform. There might be some problem with them only. Thanks anyways!